# Variable assigned value

Tags: node.js

```
const questions = [
    "What is your name ?",
    "Your City : ",
    "Your Country : "
];
const collectAnswers = (questions, done) =>{
    const answers = [];
    const [firstQ] = questions;
```

here, I want to ask that what will be the value stored in `const [firstQ] = questions` ?
Is it hold every text an array or just the text on first index of an array ?

Comment: Try it out and see. (it'll just be the first index)

Answer (score 1):

This is [array destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), meaning that it will assign the value of the first item in the `questions` array to a variable named `firstQ`.

You can do this with as many array elements as you want. For example:

```
const [ foo, bar, baz ] = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ];
```

This will asign the variables foo, bar, and baz to the corresponding strings from the array on the right.